# Encountered an infinite loop when using cumulative probability to draw

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

The problem is described as follows: random sampling from the 5 × 9 two-dimensional matrix according to the different probability of the elements **"p"** , a total of N = 15 non-repetitive 2D index values will be chosen, the two-dimensional array of probability "p"  has been hard-coded, and the sum of 2D **"p"** array is 1, but in many cases my program will fall into the the dead loop, within  **elif** statement, I check the problem repeatedly, an d initially thought it was problem of random number seed. Then, random seed is reset using **time.time()** each time when create a new random number but still exists a problem,
So I come to ask where the problem lies? And why this happen? what is the reason?

```
import random
import time


def pick_pisotions(how_many):
    result_positions = []
    p = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0.09200879765395895, 0.10227272727272728, 0.0988514173998045, 0.010019550342130987, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0.0024437927663734115, 0.17424242424242423, 0.44477028347996095, 0.07539100684261975, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    temp_position_list = []  # 2D positions, each item just like this format :(row, col)
    temp_p_list = []  # probability of be chosen of 2D array above
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(9):
            temp_position_list.append((row, col))
            temp_p_list.append(p[row][col])
    print("sum =", sum(temp_p_list))

    seed_index = 0
    while True:  # choose N no-repeating positions, ()
        seed_index += 1
        # random.seed(time.time())
        random.seed(seed_index)
        length_of_result = len(result_positions)
        if length_of_result == how_many:  # enough
            return result_positions
        elif 0 <= length_of_result < how_many:  # not enough
            random_number = random.uniform(0, 1)
            cumulative_probability = 0.0
            for item_position, item_probability in zip(temp_position_list, temp_p_list):
                cumulative_probability += item_probability  #
                print(" test random_number = ", random_number)
                print(" test cumulative_probability = ", cumulative_probability)

                if random_number <= cumulative_probability:
                    result_positions.append(item_position)
                    result_positions = list(set(result_positions))  #
                    break
                else:
                    print("test random_number > cumulative_probability")
                    # pass
        else:
            print("error ：pick_tiffs()")


pick_pisotions(15)
```

the dead loop always happens in here:

```
if random_number <= cumulative_probability:
    result_positions.append(item_position)
    result_positions = list(set(result_positions))  #
    break
```

My mother language is not English so some of my sentences may sounds strange :)
And waiting for your help~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just find where the problem is:

```
result_positions = list(set(result_positions))  #
```

this line remove duplicates, all my 2D "p" array only has 8 none-zero items, so "length_of_result" will never match the length of more than 8 (such as 15)
I haven't noticed this problem before.

And for getting a high-quality random number, I just find that I can use **secrets.SystemRandom** (**New in version 3.6.** A class for generating random numbers using the highest-quality sources provided by the operating system.)

```
from random import SystemRandom
from random import Random

system_random = SystemRandom(Random())
random_number = system_random.random()
```